# ListAgg and other column selection

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the output for below query

```
select 
    listagg((REGEXP_SUBSTR(ABC, '[^:]+$')),';') AS Unit , (select 'XYZ' from dual) 
from 
    MNO 
where
    BATCH in (select BATCH from PQR 
              where TYPE like 'Emp'
                and ORG like 'XYZ')
```

It works fine if I remove `(select 'XYZ' from dual)`, but I need both Unit as well as Org information.

The current query results in an error

> ORA-00937: not a single group function

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use sub-query.

```
select listagg((REGEXP_SUBSTR(ABC, '[^:]+$')),';') AS Unit , 
       'XYZ' 
  from MNO 
 where BATCH in (select BATCH from PQR where TYPE = 'Emp' and ORG = 'XYZ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting just the string literal `'XYZ'` instead of using the subquery:

```sql
SELECT
    LISTAGG(REGEXP_SUBSTR(ABC, '[^:]+$'), ';') AS Unit,
    'XYZ'
FROM MNO m
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PQR p WHERE p.BATCH = m.BATCH AND
                                        TYPE = 'Emp' AND ORG = 'XYZ');
```

Note: The logic of the `WHERE` subquery is not clear.  It is not clear whether you want to find `Emp` anywhere in the  `Type` column or you want an exact match.  For the latter, use `WHERE ... TYPE LIKE '%Emp%'`, and similar for `ORG`.

Comment: Do you want `TYPE LIKE '%Emp%'` or `TYPE = 'EMP'` ?

Comment: That part I figured it in actual query and have corrected it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need an aggregation for organization within a select statement containing `join` such as

```
SELECT p.org, LISTAGG((REGEXP_SUBSTR(m.abc, '[^:]+$')), ';') AS Unit           
  FROM MNO m
  JOIN PQR p 
    ON m.batch = p.batch
 WHERE p.type LIKE '%Emp%' -- you may replace with 'Emp%' or '%Emp' or 'Emp'
   AND p.org LIKE '%XYZ%' -- you may replace with 'XYZ%' or '%XYZ' or 'XYZ' 
 GROUP BY p.org
```